# error hasOwnProperty on DataTable checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables, jquery-datatables-checkboxes

Can somebody help me to fix my code, I try to select multiple data from `DataTable` using checkboxes `DataTables` from [gryocode](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/), the data in `console.log` success to be changed when I click other data, but I got an error asOwnProperty on DataTable checkboxes, here is my code:

```html
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#transactionsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
      var id = button.data('id');
      var modal = $(this);

      modal.find('.modal-body p#data-id').text('Id: ' + id);

      var Mytable = $('#pendingTable').DataTable({
        'destroy': true,
        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'ajax': {
          'url': '/finances/pending',
          'type': 'POST',
          'data': function (d) {
            d.myKey = id;
          }
        },
        'columnDefs': [{
          'targets': 0,
          'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
          }
        }],
        'select': {
          'style': 'multi'
        },
        'columns': [{
            'data': 'id'
          },
          {
            'data': 'id',
            'title': 'Id Order'
          },
          {
            'data': 'seller.name',
            'title': 'seller name'
          },
          {
            'data': 'status',
            'title': 'status'
          }
        ]
      });

      // Handle form submission event
      document.getElementById('selectData').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var form = $('#frm-ready');
        var rows_selected = [];
        var rows_select = Mytable.column(0).checkboxes.selected();

        rows_select.map(item => rows_selected.push(item));

        console.log(rows_selected);
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

**MyError:**

```
dataTables.checkboxes.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
  at String.<anonymous> (dataTables.checkboxes.min.js:5)
  at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
  at s.<anonymous> (dataTables.checkboxes.min.js:5)
  at s.iterator (jquery.dataTables.min.js:100)
  at s.<anonymous> (dataTables.checkboxes.min.js:5)
  at s.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:103)
  at Object.selected (jquery.dataTables.min.js:102)
  at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (finances:65)
```